# Updating a notification with both the old and the new extras

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent

When updating a notification, there's the option of either using the old extras or using the new extras. Is there any possibility to append the new extras to the old ones, i.e. to use **both** the new and the old extras?

Comment: Why can't you get that information yourself and then create a new notification containing both?

Comment: I can get the old information again, but it'd be much better to just append the new information. Or is there any way to get the extras from a notification?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _"updating a notification"_? Please post the code you use to do this.

Comment: updating means that when a new message arrive it will be clubbed with old messages not replace them just like whats app does it

Comment: Are you using `Notification.setLatestEventInfo()`?

Answer (score 0):

**You can't do that directly**, but you can do something similar:

Keep an variable with your last `Intent` (used to create the PendingIntent).

For each new `Intent`, create a *cumulative* `Intent` with the old content plus the new content:

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(oldIntent); 
//...update newIntent with the "fresh" data (or merge it following your own logic)
```

And then create your `PendingIntent` using **FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT**.